# Scaling up a UIImageView with a pinch gesture

Tags: iphone, ios, xcode, ipad

I'm using a pinch gesture to let users increase/decrease the size of an image. I temporarily manipulate that CGAffineTransform to let the user play with the scale, then just undo it and set the frame size so that image scales with quality (CGAffineTransformScale does nothing for image quality and will only stretch out the image).

```
    -(void)handlePinch:(UIPinchGestureRecognizer *)recognizer{
    if(recognizer.state == UIGestureRecognizerStateBegan){
        self.alpha = 0.7;
        startingTransform = self.transform;
    }
    recognizer.view.transform = CGAffineTransformScale(recognizer.view.transform, recognizer.scale, recognizer.scale);
    recognizer.scale = 1;
    if (recognizer.state == UIGestureRecognizerStateEnded){
        self.alpha = 1.0;
        CGRect endFrame = self.frame;
        self.transform = startingTransform;
        self.frame = endFrame;
        //self.transform = CGAffineTransformRotate(self.transform, acos(startingTransform.c)); //reapply rotation?
    }
}
```

**The issue**: The problem with my code is that it does not account for rotation. Some of my images start out rotated (with CGAffineTransformRotate being previously applied to them) and what happens when the pinch gesture finishes is that the imageview warps out into really thin rectangles, devoid of any rotation or scale they were before.

I thought I could carry over the original rotation and apply it after the frame was set, but I don't think that works. Any help is appreciated. Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Note that the [UIView documentation](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/uikit/reference/uiview_class/uiview/uiview.html) says that as soon as a UIViews transform is not its identity transform, the frame property becomes undefined and should not be used, so do not rely on `CGRect endFrame = ...` to work.

Otherwise, if you want the quality to change, just set the transform to identity, scale the frame and then reapply the transform to keep the rotation. That should work fine.

Comment: Hi, what does "transform to identity" mean? Also, how do you scale the frame, do you mean using the pinch gesture scale to manipulate frame.size.width/height rather than CGAffineTransformScale? Thanks

Comment: an identity transform is basically a transform that does nothing, does not scale, rotate or skew. by scaling the frame i do mean manipulating the frames size, yes but keep in mind that you will have to reposition the view accordingly, preferrably via saving view.center before scaling and reapplying it afterwards

Answer (score 1):

add imageview as subview of scrollview, and then specify the delegate of scrolview which asks for viewtobezoomed as the imageview. it will easi.y solve it.

http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/uikit/reference/uiscrollviewdelegate_protocol/Reference/UIScrollViewDelegate.html#//apple_ref/occ/intfm/UIScrollViewDelegate/viewForZoomingInScrollView:

Comment: Thanks for the reply, but this is for zooming into the image, correct? Not scaling it up in size overall?

Comment: scrolview's zoomscale will give you the scale. once user decides appropriate scale you can apply it to the image. After all we have to just give user the feel, right?